# why does useEffect proc twice when i add an additional condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a countdown timer but i hit something interesting...

This code procs twice in a row , as in the useEffect runs twice per second.

```
'use client'
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)
  let intervalId = useRef(null)
  const start=()=>{
    setTimer(900)
    intervalId.current = setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer((timer)=>timer-1)
    }, 1000) 
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (timer < 1 && timer != null) {
      setTimer(null)
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      console.log("proccccccccccccc")
    }
  }, [timer])

  useEffect(()=>{
    start()
  }, [])

  return (
    <main className="">
       {timer}
    </main>
  )
}
```

this procs once per second ( remove the condition && timer != null at useEffect )

```
'use client'
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)
  let intervalId = useRef(null)
  const start=()=>{
    setTimer(900)
    intervalId.current = setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer((timer)=>timer-1)
    }, 1000) 
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (timer < 1) {
      setTimer(null)
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      console.log("proccccccccccccc")
    }
  }, [timer])

  useEffect(()=>{
    start()
  }, [])

  return (
    <main className="">
       {timer}
    </main>
  )
}
```

I couldnt for the life of me understand why despite reading it many times over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be because you are running your app in strict mode. Check if in index.js the `React.StrictMode` element is present. This will render everything twice to detect problems. Building the app for production (`npm build`) will have it working as expected. But you can also remove the strict mode element if you wish--it may not detect all problems anymore, but I usually remove it as it's too much to compensate for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the server in development mode? If so, that is [intended behavior and won't affect production builds](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode). If you really need to, you can remove it by disabling strict mode. You can do that by removing the `<React.StrictMode>` tags in your `App.js` file.

Strict mode is used to find bugs in your app. It will re-run effects and renders to find bugs caused by impure rendering and identify faulty effect cleanup. I heavily recommend you continue using it unless you're sure you have a reason not to.